# ORA-31013 when reading a JSON_VALUE from a JSON_TABLE

Tags: sql, json, oracle

When I query a `JSON_TABLE` for a value using a `JSON_VALUE` expression (and not a `COLUMN` in the table expression) such as:

```
WITH SAMPLE_TABLE AS (
  SELECT '{"a":[{"b":"foo"},{"b":"bar"}]}' AS PAYLOAD FROM DUAL
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(SUB, '$.b') 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE, JSON_TABLE(
  PAYLOAD, 
  '$.a[*]' 
  COLUMNS (SUB CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$')
);
```

I get an error that I am using an invalid XPATH expression (ORA-31013: Invalid XPATH expression). The message alone confuses me but if I change the select to `JSON_VALUE(TO_CHAR(SUB), '$.b')`, the query works by showing two rows *foo* and *bar* what confuses me even more.

I do not have any such problems when using the XML-equivalent in Oracle where such selects just work. I am not using columns as this allows me to reuse a lot of stuff I already have for XML and beyond that, I am curious what is wrong here. I am using *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0*.

Answer (score 0):

can you refer the json field using dot notation as mentioned in oracle 19c. Hope you are using oracle latest version.

reference : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-in-oracle-database.html#GUID-D7BCE045-EF6D-47E9-9BB2-30C01933248E

example

```
SELECT po.po_document.Requestor FROM j_purchaseorder po;
```

Here
j_purchaseorder po is a table.
po_document  is json database field
Requestor is json key

Could you try this.